# How can I set a title at the top of a customized Brightcove UI player?

Tags: ios, swift, brightcove

[In this tutorial](https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/ios-player-samples/blob/master/PlayerUI/PlayerUICustomization/swift/PlayerUICustomization/CustomLayouts.swift) The UI is built using 'lines' of views from the bottom. Which is perfect for just a traditional bottom view like the one with progress bar below, but I want to have a title label like the example too. I can't add empty lines of views as the screens differs.

Should I build a new custom `UIView` from scratch?

[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Can you be more specific about what exactly you want to achieve as well as what are the problems which are preventing you from reaching that goal? For example, what do you mean by "the screens differs"?

Comment: I want to design a screen like this: https://learning-services-media.brightcove.com/doc-assets/device-sdks/android/overview/native-player-controls/controls-android-custom.png , the title is at the top, no matter it's iPad's or iPhone's screen.

Comment: The UI you posted in Android is probably best matched in iOS with a `UINavigationBar`. If you intend on using your application to play media, [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller) may be relevant as well.

Comment: I guess the title won't be implemented as UINavigationBar, it's just a label. And the picture has nothing to do with Android, I want to implement the video player UI including the title just like that :)

Comment: I don't even know why my question got downvoted by someone careless enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of search, the answer was actually in the repository: https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/ios-player-samples/tree/master/Player/CustomControls

There is an nib file which has the UIView as custom controls view to the video player, which is much easier to implement and has much more freedom to design as you wish.